# Does anyone know what this table is called?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I came across this table but I don't know what this table is known as:

[image]

It was present in the explanation to a problem.

**The problem is:**

Harry and Ron told me separately how many times they watched the movie Titanic. I told them "you guys both watched it, but one of you watched it once more than the other.". Then they had the following conversation:

Ron: I have no idea if you watched Titanic more than I did.

Harry: Me neither. Do you know now?

Ron: Yes, indeed!

Harry: Really? Then so do I!

What is the possible number of times Ron watched Titanic? (Select every answer that is possible.)

**(Note: At no point did Harry and Ron watch Titanic together.)**

Does anyone knows this table and how to interpret information it contains?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think **Truth table** is not like this.

Comment: Where did you come across that table? Was it on a web page that you can share with us so that we can get the context to understand the table?

Comment: Could you provide, if possible, more information on the context?

Comment: The link requires to login with credentials. It was in explanation to a logical problem.
I have edited the question above to include the problem.

Comment: I think the table just depicts all the pairs $(h, r)$ where $h = r + 1$ or $r = h + 1$ as a subset of the plane.

Comment: @RobArthan please post it as an answer. I'll mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table depicts the pairs $(h, r)$ where $h = r + 1$ or $r = h + 1$ as a subset of the plane.